# How to handle special characters from the database in objective c?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, encoding

I am displaying data in the **tableview cell** from the **sqlite database**.

The data comes from **xml parsing** and in **Hungarian language**.

The data is inserted in the database very well(i.e with special characters). But at the time of fetching and displaying in the tableview , it is displayed as special characters as shown below ;

**EDIT :**

I have converted and inserted data in the database using follows :

```
 NSData *dataTitle = [articleElements.Title dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

 NSString * stringTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataTitle encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So in the database it is as- **"Kosaras vereség hazai pályán "**

but at the time of fetching from the database in the array , it is as - **"Kosaras veres√©g hazaip√°ly√°n"**

I have tried like this at the time of fetching -

```
NSData *data = [titleLabel.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"data = %@", str);

NSString *name2 = [NSString
                   stringWithCString:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                   encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);
```

but could not be successful.

I have searched a lot but could not be able to find the solution.

How can i do this ?

Please help me.

Thanks..

Comment: You can't convert ASCII to UTF8 like this. There might be some ways but I would suggest that you use UTF8 in your database, this reduces your problems in the future too.

Comment: @boreas  thanks for reply. But can you tell me how to do this in database ?

Comment: for me I use prepared database. If you are using a database that is generated in runtime, maybe you could refer to answer how to do that with code.

Comment: @boreas no i have created database file (.sqlite) using sqlite manager not at runtime.

Comment: but you mentioned it's from xml parsing, in that case just make sure the source has the right encoding. I know some text editors that provides encoding transfer, make sure it's utf8 before it goes into database.

Comment: @boreas ohh. i see. Means u mean to say that i should convert / encode the string /  data in utf8 before inserting in database though there is proper format data in the database ??

Comment: yes that's what I did all the time. encoding is a pain in the * and the best way is to kill it at the very beginning.

Comment: @boreas thanks again. But i checked that i have already converted / encoded data to utf8 format before inserting it. Please see my edited question.

Comment: how did the data come out of sqlite database (the variable str)? what wrapper are you using?

Comment: @boreas data come out of sqlite in the array

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your [character and string encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Right now you have encoding declared in your code as "`NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`".

The CFString equivalent for the encoding you want is ["`kCFStringEncodingISOLatin10`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html).

When I look in `NSString.h`, I see this comment:

> /* Note that in addition to the values explicitly listed below,
>   NSStringEncoding supports encodings provided by CFString. See
>   CFStringEncodingExt.h for a list of these encodings. See CFString.h
>   for functions which convert between NSStringEncoding and
>   CFStringEncoding.
>   */

So you just need to convert between CFStringEncoding and NSStringEncoding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have not specified any encoding like  **"NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding" ** , i have just tried to convert data comes from the database in the array.